# Character of an irreducible representation vanishes outside of the commutator subgroup

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, characters

I need to prove the following proposition:

> Suppose $\sigma$ is a degree -$d$ irreducible representation of a finite group $G$
> , and it is the only one of that degree up to equivalence.
>
> Then, for every $g\in G$ such that $g\notin G'$ we have that:
>
> $\chi_{\sigma}(g)=0$

We were given a hint, which is to use the following lemma in order to aid for the proof of the proposition:

> If $g\in G,g\notin G'$ then there is a degree-one representation
> $\chi:G\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^{*}$ such that $\chi(g)\neq1$ .

Now, I have proved the lemma, but I cannot wrap my head around how to use it.
My guess, is construct another degree-$d$ representation using the tensor product, and use the fact that there is only one degree-$d$ representation up to equivalence, and
since they share the same character, deduce something from it.

I would really like help in here please.
Thanks

Comment: The proposition you say you need to prove has an unexplained $\chi$ in it. Are you not trying to prove $\sigma(g)=0$ [and you do so by considering the character $\chi(g)\sigma(g)$ where $\chi$ is the one given by the lemma.]

Comment: Since there' s a unique degree $d$ irrep, $\chi_\sigma = \chi_\sigma \theta$ for any 1-d character $\theta$.  Now fix a group element $g$ outside the commutator subgroup and choose a $\theta$ which is non-1 on $g$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the kind commenters, I ended up proving the required, for the sake
of completeness I will post the solution for anyone else pondering on the same question:

**Proof of the Lemma:**

We know that $G'\triangleleft G$ so $G/G'$ is well defined.

Since $g\notin G'$ then $gG'\neq eG'$ .

Since every degree-one representation of $G$ is of the form $\pi=\phi\circ\psi:G\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^{*}$

where :

$\psi:G\rightarrow G/G'$

$g\mapsto gG'$

and $\phi:G/G'\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^{*}$

is an irreducible representation of abelian group therefore one-dimentional, then:

$\pi(g)=\phi(gG')\neq\phi(eG')=1$

**Proof of the Proposition:**

Let $\pi:G\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^{*}$ be a degree-one representation of $G$ such that $\pi(g)\neq1$.

$\tau:=\sigma\otimes\pi$ is also a degree -$d$ representation of $G$.

Let $g\in G$ where $g\notin G'$ .

$\chi_{\tau}(g)=\chi_{\sigma}(g)\chi_{\pi}(g)=\chi_{\sigma}(g)\pi(g)$

Since there is a unique irreducible representation of degree-$d$ up to equivalence then:

$\chi_{\sigma}(g)=\chi_{\tau}(g)=\chi_{\sigma}(g)\pi(g)$

$\Rightarrow\chi_{\sigma}(g)(1-\pi(g))=0$

for every $g\in G$ thus for $g\notin G'$ we have that $\pi(g)\neq1$ which means:

$1-\pi(g)\neq0$ thus $\chi_{\sigma}(g)=0$ .$\square$